# Convergence of steepest gradient descent

Tags: convergence-divergence, optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

The description of gradient descent in Wikipedia says:
$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \gamma_n\nabla F(x_n)$$ for $n = 0,1,2,...$

Suppose that $x_n$ converges to $x$.

Then, is it always true that $\nabla F(x) = 0$?

Can $x$ be a saddle point of $F$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x_n$ converges to $x^*$, then the gradient at that location is zero ($\nabla F(x^*) = 0$):
$$x^* = x^* - \gamma_n \nabla F(x^*) $$
$$ \nabla F(x^*) = 0$$

If the function $F(x)$ is convex, then $x^*$ is guaranteed to be a minimizer of $F(x)$. However, in general, the point $x^*$ may be a saddle point of the function.

Comment: How can I get $$x^* = x^* - \gamma_n \nabla F(x^*) $$?

Comment: The method converges when the update doesn't change: $x_{n+1} = x_n$. This means that $x_{n+1} = x_n = x_n - \gamma_n \nabla F(x_n)$, which occurs when $\nabla F(x_n) = 0$. (Above, I used the point $x^*$ as the converged point, but in this comment, I called it $x_n$. Sorry to change notation!)